# Adding error bars in ggplot2 produces overlapped bars

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have the following data table `msumNZ`

```
msumNZ <-  data.frame(
      Habitat = c(rep("Core", 6), rep("Wild", 6)),
      Parameter = rep(c("AlertForaging", "Foraging", "NA_OutOfSight ", 
                        "Other", "Social", "Vigilance"),2),
      mCounts = c(4.23, 5.74, 3.48, 4.93, 2.65, 4.31,
                  3.68, 5.9,  3.94, 3.82, 2.94, 4.83), 
      sd = c(3.63, 3.41, 2.73, 3.82, 1.93, 3.15, 
             1.93, 3.23, 3.32, 3.67, 2.15, 3.24))
```

Which I am plotting as a bar chart with ggplot:

```
ggplot(mdta.summary.NZ, aes(x = Parameter, y = mCounts, fill = Habitat)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge())
```

Which gives the following graph:
[image]

Now I want to add error bars based on the sd variable for which I add to the above code the following:

```
+ geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mCounts, ymax = mCounts + sd, width = 0.2))
```

However, I do not get error bars for each x parameter by habitat but what seems to be an overlap of the two.

[image]

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to set `position` of error bar as `position_dodge()` just as `geom_bar()`, along with width to adjust the location of error bars.

Second, the `ymin` needs to be set as `mCounts-sd`, just like ymax (`mCounts + sd`),

```r
library(ggplot2)
msumNZ <-  data.frame(
  Habitat = c(rep("Core", 6), rep("Wild", 6)),
  Parameter = rep(c("AlertForaging", "Foraging", "NA_OutOfSight ", 
                    "Other", "Social", "Vigilance"),2),
  mCounts = c(4.23, 5.74, 3.48, 4.93, 2.65, 4.31,
              3.68, 5.9,  3.94, 3.82, 2.94, 4.83), 
  sd = c(3.63, 3.41, 2.73, 3.82, 1.93, 3.15, 
         1.93, 3.23, 3.32, 3.67, 2.15, 3.24))

ggplot(msumNZ, aes(x = Parameter, y = mCounts, fill = Habitat)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mCounts-sd, ymax = mCounts + sd, width = 0.2),
                position = position_dodge(width = .9))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks you very much. The ymin = mCounts was on purpose but it certainly looks better with conventional error bars. Thanks again.

Comment: Please accept the answer if you solved the problem with this :)